# Custom Post Type - Single-{slug}.php to override Single-{$posttype}.php in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I am looking to add a custom template for a single post inside of a Custom Post Type. The Custom Post Type is working as it should and all of the posts are correctly using single-{$posttype}.php. However, for the page with the slug "our-wedding", I am trying to override single-{$posttype}.php and have it use single-our-wedding.php. However, the page is still using single-{$posttype}.php.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a solution that will let you assign custom templates to one particular post of that post type (there are plugins).

Or you can edit the single-{$posttype}.php to include a

```
if( is_single('our-wedding') ){
   get_template_part( 'my-template');
} else {
   // The usual code for this single-posttype
}
```

And then create a file called "my-template.php" inside your theme folder.

(Edited based on user feedback.)

Comment: Are you referring to "Our Wedding" as a custom post type, or as a page inside Wordpress?

Comment: "Our Wedding" is a post inside the Custom Post Type "photos".

Comment: Let me know if that works for you, and consider marking as answered if it did.